# Accuracy does not go up on a keras model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm trying to train a model on data from the Higgs Boson challenge on kaggle. The first thing I decided to do was to create a simple keras model. I've tried different amount and width of layers, different cost functions, different optimizers different functions in neurons, but the accuracy on the training set is always between 0.65-0.7 range. I don't really understand why. Here's my an example of a model that worked so weird:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, merge, Activation, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(600, input_shape=(30,),activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(400, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train,labels,nb_epoch=1,batch_size=1)
```

I also tried larger models and got such an accuracy too. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT**

I have tried training this model with 100 epochs and the batch size 0f 100 and got loss equal to 4.9528 and accuracy to 0.6924 again. And it always outputs zero for every example.

Comment: Your edit comment shows that your data is not balanced and that is a problem. Either balance both classes in your data or use class_weight in the fit function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem arise from the fact that your model always outputs the majority class. It's not a weighted problem (one of the classes appears more than the other) and it seems that your network "learns" to always output the same class.

Try using a different classifier (Random Forest for example) and you'll see that the accuracy is much better.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When trying to address the issue with the neural network I uses SMOTE to balance the train dataset. You should use "adam" as the optimizer for the classification. Also, a much smaller network architecture should be enough for this problem.

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

df = pd.read_csv("training.csv")
y = np.array(df['Label'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x=='s' else 1))
X = np.array(df.drop(["EventId","Label"], axis=1))
sm = SMOTE()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
X_res, y_res = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(25, input_shape=(31,),activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_res, y_res,validation_data=(X_test, y_test),nb_epoch=100,batch_size=100)
```

An example results:

```
    Epoch 11/100
230546/230546 [==============================] - 5s - loss: 0.5146 - acc: 0.7547 - val_loss: 0.3365 - val_acc: 0.9138
Epoch 12/100
230546/230546 [==============================] - 5s - loss: 0.4740 - acc: 0.7857 - val_loss: 0.3033 - val_acc: 0.9270
Epoch 13/100
230546/230546 [==============================] - 5s - loss: 0.4171 - acc: 0.8295 - val_loss: 0.2821 - val_acc: 0.9195
```

Answer (score 2):

You are training way too short

> model.fit(train,labels,nb_epoch=1,batch_size=1)

this means you are going **once** through the data, with extremely small batch, it should be something among the lines of

```
model.fit(train, labels, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=100)
```

Comment: I have tried 100 epochs with the batch size of 100 and accuracy is again 0.6924, while the loss is 4.9528.  Yet it always predicts 0 now.